# Is this video game piece physically playable?

Tags: piano, technique

This is a video game track that got translated into this piano sheet, the original track was made with software I'm wondering if this middle solo is physically playable?

4/4 tempo: 152 
appears to have some parts in mezzo forte, as you can see it uses crescendos and decrescendos that seems too difficult for such tempo but these are vital for the original feeling

[image]

Comment: What game is this from? Is there a recording of it somewhere?

Comment: @corsiKa I'm not sure what game it's from, but I've done my best to turn the sheet music into [a chiptune](http://bit.ly/2L38EKY). Perhaps someone will be able to recognize it...

Comment: Looks like "Flowering Night" from the Touhou series.

Comment: If you want, you could turn staff 48 into a 7/8 one, in order to have the left hand notes on the beats in 4/4 afterwards.

Comment: @Dekkadeci [That seems to be it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wFRIWFraWQ) (the sheet shown in this question starts at 1:39). Doesn't sound at all inhuman to me. Not a beginner piece, sure (I wouldn't be able to play it at all). However, in that version, the 16th notes that start  from measure 43 seems to continue past measure 49 while the melody written here isn't played on piano at all.

Comment: No polyrhythms, no syncopation, ... trivial for any decent pianist.

Comment: another related question would be how accurate is the arrangement to the original. if the person who made this arrangement made it so it *IS* playable, what did they change to make it so? just food for thought. if it is not a direct transcription and you are having trouble playing it could you modify it to make it playable while still capturing the essence of the piece?

Comment: With a bunch of practice I reckon I could manage this. It's fast but not particularly crazy in technical terms.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I find rhythmic complexity a lot easier to handle than tricky runs of fast notes.

Comment: @KyleStrand even , say,  triplets in LH and fives in RH?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes. The challenge there is purely mental, not mechanical, and there are a variety of ways to approach it. Compared to something like the *ppp* runs of 32nds or 64ths in Ravel, that seems much easier.

Answer (score 27):

There's nothing impossible in the notation; sure, it's fast, and there's an unhealthy obsession with semiquavers, but I'm pretty sure that it could be played.

Could I play it? No. But that's because I'm not motivated enough to practice it. Or actually talented, but that's beside the point. Could the average pianist play it? Maybe. Could a professional? Sure; see Flight of the Bumblebee.

The expression is not a big problem. You'll get some of that naturally, as it follows the contour of the melody. And it's not that dramatic anyway.

In short, I'm sure someone could play it. Is it you? I don't know, but you might as well give it a go.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. By most accounts, [La Campanella](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxBs9xoUSBE) should be unplayable, and yet some people manage to pull it off. This is much simpler.

Answer (score 14):

This doesn’t look especially on the verge of impossibility; there are, as just one example, Ligeti piano etudes that are *far* more difficult than this, and pianists play those. At any rate, there’s *nothing* problematic about the dynamics at all, it’s weird to suggest that.

Comment: I don't think you need go as far as Ligeti for a counter-example. Some of the Chopin and Debussy etudes make this look pretty straightforward.

Comment: I was surprised the dynamics were mentioned as a problem, too. If you've practiced the piece enough to be able to play the notes correctly and in time, you should have enough control to play them as loud or soft as you want.

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer, but I don't have enough rep to make a comment...

As the comments stated, the song is Flowering Night from the Touhou series.

Yes, it is possible to play such Touhou songs on the piano. [Here is someone playing this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xn_dn01Ecs) (at 1:25 it lines up with the sheet music). He is probably playing it slower than original though. [Here is another pianist playing another Touhou song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=223_K43iILM) - not the one you have shown, but also having quick notes. That last pianist - marasy - can play a lot of Touhou songs, even the fast ones. Though I can't find a video of him playing Flowering Night in particular, I am sure he would be able to play such a piece.

Comment: Wasn't surprised (or instead, I *expected*) marasy's *Mokou's Theme* was linked here! Anyway, seems he hasn't (didn't) play the original song, but he did play one of the famous arrangements of the song, [Night of Nights ...?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1ZHSS0lHIA)

Answer (score 0):

The almost two-octave leaps down in the 2nd ending are pretty unreasonable at that speed, though the rest of it is not too difficult at all.

Comment: If your left hand can stretch to white-note tenths, you could take the lowest of the upper-stave notes with your left thumb.

Comment: @RosieF That's an F#; you'd need to stretch a white-note tenth *plus* a half-step.

Comment: @KyleStrand Well spotted. I concede that one.

Answer (score 0):

It's playable, but at a slightly advanced level. It's best played by someone with quick hands, skill at sixteenth notes, and high skill level.